# Cannot add server to Visual Studio Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am unable to add a remote server to the Visual Studio Server Explorer for my ASP.Net website which has been running for about 9 months.

I have added a connection to the database that is working well.

The error message leads me to think I may not have the path entered correctly. I have tried a number of combinations, including using the IP Address.

Error Message:
Could not reconnect to "servername". 
Make sure that the machine name and path are valid.

Comment: Any update on this because I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it may be because I have a web site (Solution) rather than a Project.  I started out with the Express Version of Visual Studio which did not enable projects.  I hope that helps

Comment: I have a similar problem with my remote server. I am currently exploring the idea that it might be because the Server Explorer is another process than the visual studio process, and therefore needs it's own firewall right. I know it works without the firewall on.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is a remote server then may be the firewall is blocking. Check firewall in the machine in which SQL server is running.

Comment: I have aleady established a working connection to the database.